# Check what kind of document class is used

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, letters, titling

I have defined a `.sty`-file which I use in a report, which holds a lot of good information and styles for how my documents should look like. This have been working great, until when I tried making a letter. My own style loads the `titling`-package among others, and this seems to cause errors. I of course do not really need the `titling`-package in my letter, but it is necessary in my other documents. I was wondering if I could write some kind of check to only load the `titling`-package if the document class is not a letter. That way, it will work with all my other documents, and my letters.

In the included example, I have only loaded the `titling`-package, and not my personal style. The errors produced are the same.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum, 
titling
}
\signature{Your name}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
\encl{Enclosures.}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@ifclassloaded{...}` perhaps?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The LaTeX core defines `\@ifclassloaded{classname}{true branch}{false branch}` which is basically the same as `\@ifpackageloaded` for checking whether a certain package is loaded.

The class name has to be specified without the usual `.cls` extension.

Since `@` occurs in the macro name `\@ifclassloaded`, `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is needed in the document preamble, if the check occurs in a self-written package, `\makeatletter...\makeatother` **must not** appear there!

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{letter}{%
  \typeout{this uses letter class}%
}{%
  \usepackage{titling}
  \typeout{this uses another class}%
}
\makeatother    



\signature{Your name}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
\encl{Enclosures.}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @runartrollet: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Sometime between 2015 and 2023, the public command `\IfClassLoadedTF` has been added to the kernel. It does the exact same thing as `\@ifclassloaded` but (a) doesn't require `\makeatletter...\makeatother` and (b) can be used outside of the preamble.