# Check what kind of document class is used with MWE

Tags: conditionals, document-classes

I try to autodefine the preamble using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279058/check-what-kind-of-document-class-is-used) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/how-to-conditionally-define-a-new-command-in-latex) approach but do get `Undefined control sequence. \@ifundefined{\KOMAClassName }` in case I write  report for scrreprt. for both options.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{report}
%NOTE Packages, my Macros und Formatdefinitions
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Allows different font encodings and hyphenation -> ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Translates input encodings into LaTeX internal language -> ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \makeatletter
        \@ifundefined{KOMAClassName }{\newcommand{\test}{num1} }{\newcommand{\test}{num2} } %option1
        \@ifclassloaded{KOMAClassName }{\newcommand{\testb}{num1} }{\newcommand{\testb}{num2} } %option2
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{hi}
\test \\
\testb\\
\end{document}
```

Using `scrreprt` or `report` I get printed num1 and num2  for `\test` and `\testb` (which isnt also the case)

Comment: `\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{...}{...}`, i.e. no backslash

Comment: Well, you need `\@ifclassloaded{\KOMAClassName}{...}{...}`, since this does not expect a macro name. Your code tests whether the class `KOMAClassName` is loaded, which is not the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{...}{...}` since `\@ifundefined` calls

`\expandafter\ifx\csname #1 \endcsname` (after a test), i.e. it constructs the command sequence.

Here's the definition in `latex.ltx`.

```
\def\@ifundefined#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
```

But for `\@ifclassloaded` you need the class name, i.e. what `\KOMAClassName` provides for you.

The difference between the commands is just that `\@ifundefined` checks for a command name comparing it with `\relax` whereas `\@ifclassloaded` checks for a token, i.e. a class name. `KOMAClassName` means a class named `KOMAClassName` and not what `\KOMAClassName` provides (`scrreprt`, expectedly?)

I am not sure what the `\test` and `\testb` commands should do, but I think the setup should be something like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{scrreprt}
%NOTE Packages, my Macros und Formatdefinitions
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Allows different font encodings and hyphenation -> ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Translates input encodings into LaTeX internal language -> ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
    \usepackage{blindtext}
%    \providecommand{\test}{}
%    \providecommand{\testb{}
    \newif\ifstandardreport
    \makeatletter
    \@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{%
      \standardreporttrue
      \newcommand{\test}{num1} 
    }{%
      \newcommand{\test}{num2}  %option1
    }
    \ifstandardreport
    \newcommand{\testb}{num1} 
    \else
    \@ifclassloaded{\KOMAClassName}{%
      \newcommand{\testb}{num2}
    }{
      \newcommand{\testb}{num1} 
    } %option2
    \fi
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{hi}
\test \\
\testb\\
\end{document}
```

Alternatively use `\providecommand{\test}{...}` and do `\renewcommand{\test}{...}` later on in the `\@ifclassloaded` tests.

Comment: Of course, the `\KOMAClassName` test must fail if the class is not a `KOMA` class

Comment: So \@ifclassloaded{\KOMAClassName} without interweaving it with  other solutions (\@ifundefined and \newif) can not be used for that purpose as \KOMAClassName would be undefined -> compile error

Comment: @ItsmeJulian: Of course not, see my possible solution I've posted already half an hour ago, which circumvents this. Blame `KOMA`, not `LaTeX` ;-)

Comment: @ItsmeJulian KOMAClassName is not the name of any class, so it is useless and pointless to test for it. This is neither LaTeX nor KOMAs fault, this is simple user error.

Answer (score 1):

`\KOMAClassName` can be used to test if a KOMA-class is used, as they all define that command. It cannot be used to test for a special class.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{%
    \typeout{A standard class is used, but which one?}
    \@ifclassloaded{article}{%
        \typeout{This is an article document}
    }{%
        \@ifclassloaded{report}{%
            \typeout{This is a report document}
        }{%
            \@ifclassloaded{book}{%
                \typeout{This is a book document}
            }{%
                \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
                    \typeout{Memoir is in use}
                }{%
                    \typeout{Something else is going on}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}{%
        \typeout{A KOMA class is used, but which one?}
        \@ifclassloaded{scrartcl}{\typeout{scrartcl is used}
    }{%
        \@ifclassloaded{scrreprt}{%
            \typeout{scrreprt is used}
        }{%
            \@ifclassloaded{scrbook}{scrbook is loaded}{\typeout{Something else is going on}
            \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\typeout{Memoir? In this branch? Impossible}
        }{}
    }
}
}
}
\@ifclassloaded{KOMAClassName}{\typeout{Wait? What?}}{\typeout{There is no class with that name}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Wombat
\end{document}
```