# A funny bug with input, newcommand, ifthenelse in a beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, input, ifthenelse, frame

First I write a tex named thequest like:

```
\begin{quest}
Just a problem.
\end{quest}
```

Then in the main tex, I write

```
\newtheorem{quest}{Question}
\newcommand{\Fakeframe}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{
    \begin{frame}[t]
       #1
    \end{frame}
    }}
\FakeFrame{\input{thequest.tex}}
```

Then xelatex. There will be "Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }." and "Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete." But the pdf is correct.

Why????? If I don't use the ifthenelse, or just not use the input, everything will be OK. But if I use the newcommand with a ifthenelse, and that input, there must have two errors.

That's so weird.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `\Fakeframe` macro?

Comment: Actually I want to define a \Fakeframe in both beamer and article. In the beamer, it should be a frame. But in the article, it will be just a normal text. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Fundamentally your code is wrong because because `\input{thequest.tex}` is not fully expandable while [`\ifthenelse`'s argument require it to be fully expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451965/250119). But do you want to check if **`#1` itself** is empty, or the **file content** is empty?

Comment: @Ngiap Can you add a bit more background what the purpose of this macro is? Your question sounds very much like an x-y-problem. Maybe using the `beamerarticle` package would be easier than making fake frames?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279058/check-what-kind-of-document-class-is-used

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what this would be useful for: it makes little sense to check for emptiness of the argument, in that case just don't use `\FakeFrame{}`.

Anyway, `\equal` tries to expand its argument and with `\input` this fails. Use `xifthen` and `\isempty`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-quest}
\begin{quest}
Just a problem.
\end{quest}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newtheorem{quest}{Question}
\newcommand{\FakeFrame}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{%
    \begin{frame}[t]
       #1
    \end{frame}
    }}

\begin{document}

\FakeFrame{\input{\jobname-quest.tex}}

\end{document}
```

If you want to load the file only if it's not empty, then use a different strategy.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-quest}
\begin{quest}
Just a problem.
\end{quest}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-empty}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}

\newtheorem{quest}{Question}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\FakeFrameInput}{m}
 {% #1 = filename
  \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \par }
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \begin{frame}[t] \input{#1} \end{frame}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\FakeFrameInput{\jobname-quest.tex}
\FakeFrameInput{\jobname-empty.tex}

\end{document}
```

This will only produce one frame. The file is read into a token list variable in which we remove all `\par` tokens (generated by empty lines). If nothing remains (or just spaces), the file is considered empty.

Comment: WONDERFUL! Love u~

Comment: @Ngiap Look at the addition.